# How to implement a tableview cell that contains 2 more cells inside counts are not same

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I am trying to achieve a layout like this [image]

1. My tableview has 3 cells (SubItemsCell (main cell), SubItemsListCell(n number of products inside main cell) and noSubstituteCell (fixed cell after the second cell count 1))
2. SubItemsCell has a "SELECT" Button that will expand and show SubItemsListCell, this cell will load as (dynamic) any count of products under the main SubItems Cell.
3. NoSubstitute Cell comes after the n number of products loads.

What my expected result is first load main cell that is self.archivedProducts and when u click each archived product's select button it expand and load self.newproducts and nosubstitute static cell. So main cell paired up with those 2 cells and show at once when we expand only.

So far I just loaded Main Cell only. I have no idea what should I do next, please give me an idea with a code or very similar example.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 

  guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubItemsCell", for: indexPath) as? SubItemsCell else {
        fatalError ("SubstituteItems Cell not found!")
   }
    
    let product = self.archivedProducts[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = product.title ?? ""
    cell.priceLabel.text = "AED \(String(format: "%.2f", product.price ?? 0.00))"
    cell.scaleLabel.text = product.uom ?? ""
    cell.unavailableLabel.isHidden = false
    cell.selectBtn.isHidden = false
    let imageUrl = product.image?.url
    let escapedUrl = imageUrl?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
    let replacedUrl = "\(escapedUrl ?? "")"
    let url = URL(string: replacedUrl)
    let plImage = UIImage(named: "whiteBg")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    cell.thumbImage.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: plImage, options: [.transition(.fade(0.2))])
    }
```

}

Comment: tableview inside tableview...

Comment: @FahimParkar I can insert a tableView inside the cell but it wont work since tableview size will not expand according to the cell count

Comment: inside cell you will have tableview where delegate you wil give count for number of rows inside that cell...

Comment: I implemented this for limited number of static cells with a fixed size table view without scrolling but does it auto resize when cell count increases ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you *need* a nested tableview. You can achieve the above with other elements. In order to achieve the layout above, my suggestion is the following:

1. Subclass your UITableViewCell into at least 2 different formats. There's a lot of ways to do this, my suggestion is to use a CocoaTouch Class w/ XIB ([tutorial here](https://makeschool.org/mediabook/oa/tutorials/habitual-tutorial---swift-4/building-a-custom-cell/)) so you can be meticulous with the layout and constraints:

a. CellWDropdown (Cell #1 shown): You have a cell prototype that will include the image, the 3 labels in question and a button which act as the dropdown and will invoke a UIPickerView.

b. CellWStepper (Cells #2 and #3) : You'll have your image and 2 labels and what's called UIStepper for the +/- buttons

c. LastCell (Cell #4 if that's a cell? It could also be a view): likewise create the needed UI elements and constrain them appropriately.

2. Register the nib file you created:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CellWDropDown", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellWDropdownIdentifier")
```

3. In cellForRowAt method, you invoke the XIBs created above to make the cell views based on the index OR desired cell type for example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellWDropdownIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CellWDropdown
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2){
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellWStepperIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CellWStepper
    }
    //do other actions/styling
}
```

4. Hook up delegate relationships/methods between the nibs you created and the UITableViewController. This is going to application specific.

There's a lot of detail that will have to fill in the gaps but this should put a major dent in getting started

Comment: Thanks for the detail info. how to handle the numberOfRowsInSection in this case

Comment: It depends what your intent is. If the data is fixed and predictable then you can simply hard code it (i.e return 5 if you want 5 cells). If it is programmatically determined by your model you should have your data source contain some kind of array i.e. var myData = [Data]() then  return myData.count to populate # of cells according to the data model