# How to achieve expandable cell inside cell with different array counts (dynamic)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I came across [this Tutorial](https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course_video?id=2242) to achieve the results for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70593599/how-to-implement-a-tableview-cell-that-contains-2-more-cells-inside-counts-are-n/70595085?noredirect=1#comment124816084_70595085) but from this approach I can't achieve with sections according to my scenario. All I need to load an expanded cell and load the dynamic cell inside. I found many solutions with the same array count of inside cell but don't have any solutions according to this [image: example].

I need to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70593599/how-to-implement-a-tableview-cell-that-contains-2-more-cells-inside-counts-are-n/70595085?noredirect=1#comment124816084_70595085) [image: picture].

Comment: you can use heightForRowAt as UITableView.autoDimension
and hide and show view of cell as needed

Comment: do you need something like..Click on select yo show data which are dynamic

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali I need to select a maincell which is always not expanded when it's clicked it expands and load the second cell with the inside product

Comment: second cell with that extra Tick ..?

Comment: please share you email so i can send you some photos of example

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali fawasfais@gmail.com

Comment: i have sent a mail to you pls check it

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali I still Didn't receive the email. can you resend it again bro ??

Comment: please check mail